# Simple bash and curl check that a file exists on a web server?

Tags: bash, http, curl

I am trying to improve a WebDAV bash uploader to bypass uploading files when they already exist on the web server.

What should work with a HEAD request and parsing this after this.

Extra bonus if the solution would also include size verification.

Answer (score 5):

Quick and dirty: Just check if a Content-Length header is in the response?

Something like:

`curl -I http://google.com | grep Content-Length`

Then potentially parse the length using awk:

`curl -I http://google.com | grep Content-Length | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}'`

This give you the length of the content in bytes (if the file exists) or otherwise an empty string.

Comment: that's the only one working for me so far (having to use the curl option "--user user:password")

Answer (score 3):

Here is some bash code that checks if the files exists on the webserver and if it does have the same size as the one one disk.

The file is not downloaded, only checked using a HEAD request.

```
TMPFILE=$(tempfile)
FILE=location/some_file_to_upload.txt
MYVAR=http://example.com/$FILE

response=$(curl -n --silent -X HEAD $MYVAR --write-out "\n%{http_code}\n" -D $TMPFILE)
status_code=$(echo "$response" | sed -n '$p')

LOCAL_SIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILE")
SERVER_SIZE=$(cat $TMPFILE|grep -i "Content-Length" | awk 'BEGIN {RS=""}{gsub(/\r/,"",$0); print $0}' | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}')
if [ -z "$VAR" ]; then
       SERVER_SIZE=0
fi

if [ "$status_code" -lt "200" -o "$status_code" -gt "299" -o "$LOCAL_SIZE" -ne "$SERVER_SIZE" ]; then
        echo 'file does not exist or is of different size
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
status=$(curl --head --silent http://domain/object | head -n 1)
if echo "$status" | grep -q 404
  echo "Uploading"
else
  echo "Not uploading: $status"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just output the reported size, note that in the case of `http://google.com` you will get a low byte count of 219, that's because it's a 301 redirect. To get curl to follow the links to the actual file and report the file size you can use the `-L --post301` options:

`curl -s -o /dev/random -w '%{size_download}' http://google.com`

219

`curl -L --post301 -s -o /dev/random -w '%{size_download}' http://google.com`

18942

(Note: On non-Linux systems change `/dev/random` to `/dev/null`.)